# How can I type accented characters like ë?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Currently I use the character palette applet in gnome panel to put special characters into text.

This is okay, but I have to stop typing, select the character I want from the applet and then copy and paste.

Is there a way to simply type special characters with different key combinations? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Run `gucharmap`. Applications -> Accessories -> Character map.

Comment: Do for the compose key in right alt `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"`. Source http://askubuntu.com/a/784005/25388

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz in Ubuntu 20.04, to enable the Compose key via a GUI, I was able to use in gnome-tweaks

Comment: This is an old question... today on most distrib you'll find a US French keyboard that makes things easy :)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Often this is easier with the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey). With that configured you use key combos to get the special characters. For instance:

- For `ë` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>.
- For `ẽ` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>.
- For `ô` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>.
- For `á` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>.
- For `à` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>.
- For `€` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>.
- For `£` you press <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>.

Note that you do not have to hold down the compose key; just press each key in order.

To set the compose key go to `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard, then Layouts` -> `Options`. Open up Compose Key Position and choose a key. I use <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Spot on, except for one thing - you don't need to hold down the compose key at all. Just hit the compose key, `, then a, and voilà!

Comment: Yep. You're right. Habit made me think that it was actually required.

Comment: +1 for allowing me to get rid of the special characters panel applet

Comment: I recommend assigning the Compose key to Caps Lock, which I am pretty sure only comes standard on keyboards to annoy people.

Comment: @tyjkenn Actually <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> can be useful on other keyboard layouts. For instance, in the French layout, <kbd>2</kbd> shares its position with "é". <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> will print "É" instead of "é" on Linux (on Windows, you get "2").

Comment: @DaveJennings : Where can I get list of `"`, `~`, `^`, etc with their **use** in compose key?

Comment: á <-- it worked!

Comment: @Pandya, perhaps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable is the answer for the list of available "compositions"

Comment: At least for Ubuntu 16.04 the described path doesn't work. Neither is there a preferences section in System (it's called System Settings), nor is there a Layout section in Keyboards (it's called Keyboard, without s).

Comment: @MERose, I use Ubuntu Mate these days, and it does still have that path in 16.04, but perhaps mainline Ubuntu no longer does

Comment: This worked in KDE5 as well.

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu 19.10.  See @léo-léopold-hertz comment under the question for a `gsettings` solution that works.

Comment: This is the answer for distros from 10 years ago (which reflects the documentation, ironically). Neither one works for 20.04. The question needs to be tagged as ubuntu-10 or something.

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesn't work on my system. The `compose`+key press produces a character immidiately. So to get é I would press compose+¨ then e. But then I get ´e.

Answer (score 39):

If you know the unicode value of the character you'd like to type, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
and then type the unicode.

Example:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

results in λ.

Comment: I seriously didn't know this was possible. Many thanks. For anyone wondering where to find the unicode umm... codes, http://www.unicode.org/charts/index.html is the place to go.

Comment: Seriously, only people on Windows do that.

Comment: do you know how to do this in wps office?

Comment: @taneli also you can use other way. click the Keyboard Layout Icon on the top bar, then click the Character Map link in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @rds I disagree. I've been a Linux user since 1994 and taught many other users the hex method since my 80's DOS days.  From around 2008, I started to teach them how to use US-Intl-AltGR + Compose instead.  So maybe you mean to say "few new users rely on the hex code method".

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I press `CTRL-SHIFT+U` and nothing happens, then i start typing the code and it just writes those digits into the text editor and when i press enter it just make a new line.
It this only for the English keyboard/locale?

Answer (score 16):

Here is an answer close to [1st answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368/32413), with a little alternative: **I do not need to use** <kbd>compose</kbd> because I set my keyboard to [English US international](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International) instead of **English US** or **English UK**.
So I use the following combo:
<kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> for <kbd>ë</kbd>
<kbd>'</kbd>  then <kbd>e</kbd> for <kbd>é</kbd>
<kbd>`</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> for <kbd>è</kbd>
<kbd>`</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> for <kbd>à</kbd>
<kbd>~</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd> for <kbd>ñ</kbd>

and
<kbd>"</kbd> then <kbd>spaceBar</kbd> for <kbd>"</kbd>
<kbd>'</kbd> then <kbd>spaceBar</kbd> for <kbd>'</kbd>
<kbd>`</kbd> then <kbd>spaceBar</kbd> for <kbd>`</kbd>
<kbd>~</kbd> then <kbd>spaceBar</kbd> for <kbd>~</kbd>
<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> plus <kbd>5</kbd> for <kbd>€</kbd>

Comment: Is this still the case in Ubuntu 15.10? I don't get this working anymore. Setting either 'English (US, international, with dead keys)' or 'English (international, dead keys via AltGr)' doesn't work.

Comment: I've found that setting the 'English (US, international, with dead keys)' actually works if set via `lxkeymap` (`sudo apt-get install lxkeymap`). Even more interesting, it only needs to be set once, as if some extra config is changed to make it work. (Dutch source: https://sites.google.com/site/computertip/toetsenbord)

Comment: @Lode sorry I ve not install 15.10 yet.

Comment: This is imho the actual answer, at least for all (Dutch) users coming from Windows.

Comment: As a programmer, dead keys are a deal breaker. I use the ~, ', ", ` a lot in programs and having to hit two keys would be terrible. Using the Compose key is much easier for me. I don't do much typing with diacritics, luckily.

Comment: There's no such keyboard included with Gnome.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to set your keyboard layout to USA International (AltGr dead keys), then use <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>whatever</kbd> to get the character you want. Obviously this does not work for all international/special characters, so if you need one that's not available through this method, use one of the other methods listed here.

Wikipedia gives us a [handy diagram of the available characters and the keys they are mapped to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aKB_US-International.svg).

Comment: It's also relatively easy to edit a keyboard layout file and tailor it to one's needs: — – «» “” …

Comment: Most local keyboard layouts (e.g. Belgian, French, etc.) also support AltGr, but the selection and location of special characters will be different.  The exact layout can be seen on a similar diagram from inside the keyboard configuration.

Comment: Using `English (international AltGr dead keys)` as keyboard layout, use Right-Alt + R to get `ë`/`Ë`. Right-Alt + Q = `ä`/`Ä`; Right-Alt + P = `ö`/`Ö`; Right-Alt + Y = `ü`/`Ü`; Right-Alt + S = `ß`

Comment: `Alt-Gr` + dead key is available from scratch. It saved my life when selecting a Wi-Fi hotspot with a special character in the name, as I was performing a fresh Ubuntu install.

Comment: Thanks, but many accented characters are missing in the default keyboard chart, like there is ç but no ş and no š either - but fractional numbers like ¾ and a thorn character. Looks like a leftover from some 8-bit MS-DOS page or some other US-American notion of "international".

Answer (score 6):

Note for dummies like myself. It took me a while...

1. Press Cont & Shift & u together
2. Let go of all three keys
3. input code (for example: 00e1 for á)
4. Enter

Comment: Can you imagine someone writing a long text with accented characters using your approach?! It's not feasible.

Comment: You don't need the leading zeroes. Just `e1` will work for á.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 :

Go to **Setting** > **Region** **and** **language** > on the **Input** **Sources** Click on "**+**" button and choose **English (United States)** then **English(US,intl.,with dead keys)**.

' + e -> é 
" + e -> ë 
` + e -> è 
etc.

Comment: The exact same answer was [already posted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/78047/1040551) by user **Boris**, and with a better explanation, yet it seems like this is a good extra step since later versions do not fully support their method (as commented).

Comment: It's not the same answer. Oussama provided the only solution that works for the latest releases of Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22 and that keyboard option no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and type Unicode number of the sign you want to type. So for ē you have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>113</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl + U  is unlderline.

Answer (score 1):

The compose key it's defined to do key combinations. It's Used to produce special characters like tildes and accents. To see the list of key names open /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst and search for "compose".

This technique was tested in Lubuntu. Two ways to enter special characters:

1. Call setxkbmap to define compose key in the current session
2. Define compose key permanently

1). Command line `$ setxkbmap -option "compose:rwin"`. Example to define compose key right 'Win'.

2). Open file `/etc/default/keyboard and add line XKBOPTIONS="compose:rwin"` (requires restart).

Example to write character ã after defining compose key. Press the compose key, then key 'a' and finally the tilde (AltGr + 4).

https://www.eovao.com/en/a/special%20characters%20ubuntu%20linux/5/how-to-enter-special-characters,-accents-and-tildes-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Change your keyboard layout to us. intl with dead keys

Go to

Control center > keyboard > layout > add > set country to us > Select us intl. with dead keys.