# Ways to enter special characters? Is Alt+Numpad possible?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I know there's this question [How can I type special characters like ë?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-special-characters-like-e), but I'd like to know if there is any possibility to configure the keyboard to use windowish style to insert special characters (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Code in numpad).
I know it can be done with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+Code but...

1. I have to enable ibus and don't know how to leave it enabled by default
2. <strike>Hex codes are longer than decimal ones</strike> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+Hex codes combos are longer than the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Decimal code ones
3. As an ex-Windows(TM) user, I'm so used to it....

Two examples of characters I use a lot, comparing win style and gnome-style

```
Tilde (~) character
Windows -> Alt+1-2-6
gnome -> Ctrl+Shift+U+7-e

Superscript 2 - square (²) character
Windows -> Alt+2-5-3
gnome -> Ctrl+Shift+u+b-e
```

If you try those 'key combos', the windows style is easier to type (not being subjective: less fingers used simultaneously, less keys pressed).

As I don't want to put it in some subjective way, my question would be it I can configure the keyboard to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Numpad style, or if I need to stick to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+U combo (or the compose key alternative)

Comment: For Ctrl+Shift+u + HEX to work, you need to disable IBus.With IBus enabled this feature does not work.

Comment: "Hex codes are longer than decimal ones" <- assuming you mean characterwise, that's not true. The higher your base, the shorter a big number will be able to be represented.

Comment: I thought it was right the opposite... in fact, i have had to sart ibus-daemon a few minutes ago to test the Ctrl*Shift+U thing.... It wasn't working before I started it.

Comment: @Ward: you're right... i'll rewrite that in the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use compose sequences which are more usable than the Alt+num method in Windows.
For more see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable

For example, <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> = ™

Comment: Already seen that... So guess your answer is "No, you can't use Alt+Numpad"... on a side note... is there a default compose key or must I select one in the keyboard settings?

Comment: When you enable the compose key, you select which one to use. There is no default. Most common choice is RightWin.

Comment: To implement Alt+Numpad would require a lot of work as it might interfere with Alt+number shortcuts.

Comment: The compose key seems to be the only way to go here... Even though you have to learn the key combos. I'll miss the Alt+NumPad. So, if there's no other brilliant answer, I'll mark yours as the accepted one.

Comment: How is more usable than Windows `Alt+num`?, you have to press more keys , configure a compose key and rememeber a lot more codes !

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd> works fine (under XUbuntu 15.10 and most likely under many other X11-based versions). In contrast to the compose-key method it allows the input of **any** UTF-8 character. E.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> +<kbd>Space</kbd> yields `☺`.

Of course, I use the compose-key method whenever applicable.

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+U` then `00A0` worked for non-breaking space. Thanks :-)

Comment: I think it should be the accepted answer