# Alt + ASCII code like in Windows

Tags: unicode, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to enter special characters? Is Alt+Numpad possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23330/ways-to-enter-special-characters-is-altnumpad-possible)

Is there a way to do <kbd>Alt+</kbd>ASCII code for typing ASCII code in Ubuntu like one can do in Windows? If so, then how to do it?

I understand there is a way to do <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+</kbd>Unicode code, but I would like to do it in Windows style.

Answer (score 0):

As covered by others in https://superuser.com/questions/196673/producing-a-specific-ascii-character-in-ubuntu, I'm afraid not.

I've done it with DOS related operating systems but not with Unix related ones. The codes were generated within BIOS with the initial PC's. Linux starts with raw key codes and does its own thing to figure out what code point you want. It now runs on many platforms.

The compose key may be your best bet if you don't want to use the Unicode sequence. The compose key is defined in the Keyboard Layout -> Options window.

Of course you can use the Unicode sequence to type in the first 128 bytes of ASCII, but it involves extra keys and keystrokes. If you mind those, or if you want the extended ASCII characters and find it easier to remember the extended ASCII code points, I'm sorry but I don't think there's a good answer for you.

PC BIOS Source: IBM P/N 6361453 page 5-59 and 5-60.