# How to use Windows Alt codes in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

This question was asked many times already:

[Using ALT + Keycode for accents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32764/using-alt-keycode-for-accents)

[Ways to enter special characters? Is Alt+Numpad possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23330/ways-to-enter-special-characters-is-altnumpad-possible)

[How can I type ASCII characters like Alt + numpad in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88347/how-can-i-type-ascii-characters-like-alt-numpad-in-windows)

But none of the answers actually solve my problem. The proposed solution, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is not answer to question how to use windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes.

After many months I have finally persuaded my mum to move from Vista to Ubuntu. But the <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes are not working there. Teach her to use the Unicode codes is not really a viable option.

**Is there a way to enable the Alt codes in Ubuntu?** If not native way, maybe recompiling keyboard driver, creating some wrapper, etc...

*Again I'm not asking for the Unicode solution.*

Comment: Besides @fabby 's answer this is the method we use in Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/32793/15811 Oh and do not underestimate your mother. My seventy year old mother had not problems using composed keys ;)

Comment: Trick to do this Open browser > f12 > elements tab > write the corresponding html code of that alt code> click outside > copy that symbol and enjoy Thank me later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm very sorry to say but you want Ubuntu to be Windows, which is not going to happen tomorrow...  **:-(**

Ubuntu is based on Linux, and although it has "windows" than can be dragged around a "desktop" and that it adheres to the [CUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) like Windows, it's *just not the same thing!*  Asking for something *and ruling out all possible answers* is just going to leave you with an answer like this:

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news, but what you're asking for is impossible...*

Comment: It is definitely not impossible. I am also somewhat interested in adding functionality to the Linux keyboard behaviour, specifically adding real Unicode keys (i.e. I would like to use characters of multiple languages without dead keys, Compose key, Ctrl+Shuft+U etc.). However, this will be a long term hobby project, because it seems  the keyboard handling code is scattered over the kernel, X, console code.

Comment: However, I think that the Compose key is much better than ALT + numpad, if most required characters have a Compose sequence. And even if not, AFAIK it can be customized.

Comment: @HontváriLevente *Nothing* is *impossible* in FLOSS!  What I *should have said* was: "You're not going to get this done without programming skills and getting Linus Torvalds himself to accept your code into the kernel"...  ;-)  "Impossible" is just the next best thing...  **>:)**

Comment: Fair enough. I misread the question and assumed that jnovacho was ready to modify the driver, but he only wrote that he was ready to recompile it.

Comment: @HontváriLevente If the modification would mean to change few lines, for the most used keys (@, $, §) I would be okay with that. It's just that I don't have time and skill to do complete overhaul of kernel module. I will go with *it's not possible*. The other answers were how to do X the Y way, which was not something I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's correct that you cannot type alt key codes, there is an alternative. You can enable the 'compose' key to enter special characters:

[How to enable compose key in Gnome](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html)

[Compose key combos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Common_compose_combinations)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which hopefully is more universal since compose key does not exist in my very old version of ubuntu, plus my keyboard does not even have a physical compose key.

The technique is simply switching languages for your keyboard. The new language keyboard does have keys and combos for inserting special characters already built-in.

Therefore, simply:

- Add the new language in settings: Region & Language (if you cannot find your language click on the three dots, other, more, etc and new languages should show in the list).
- Switch between languages either from the top bar or using the default shortcuts for keyboard switching `Super`+`Space` or `Shift`+`Super`+`Space` (Super is the Windows Symbol Key)
- Finally apply the key or combo for that special character.

Say you want to add Spanish accents and you have a US American keyboard then the combo should be `'`+`vowel` (obtaining á,é,...). Lastly, switch back to your language.

Comment: Practically nobody I know has a keyboard with a physical compose key. Many DEs have an option to map some other key (usually left Alt, IIRC) to the compose key. That's what we use.