# Is there a way of activating AltGr as a means of putting accents on vowels?

Tags: keyboard, text

On Windows, I use the AltGr key to input european characters into my text when contacting foreign clents. Is there a way of getting the same function in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you do with those characters. I didn't get the problem.

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-special-characters-like-e), perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Compose Key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey).

For 11.04 go to system settings; keyboard; layout and click options. Now find Compose Key and set it to Right Alt.