# How can I input punctuation marks like ellipsis?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, special-characters, input-method, unicode-entry

In Mac OS X there are ways to input punctuation marks by combination of some keystrokes.  For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> inputs a precomposed ellipsis character (`…`, U+2026).  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> opens a curly double quote character (`“`, U+201C).  Is there any way to input such punctuation marks in simple combination of keystrokes in Ubuntu?

The following is a list of characters I want to use:

- `‘` (U+2018): Single quote opening
- `’` (U+2019): Single quote closing
- `“` (U+201C): Double quote opening
- `”` (U+201D): Double quote closing
- `…` (U+2026): Precomposed ellipsis
- `—` (U+2014): Em dash
- `–` (U+2013): En dash

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-special-characters-like-e

Comment: That's ok, but what if I have switched my alternate keyboard? Then I have to switch keyborad, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, enter <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+U, 2026, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then switch back to my alternate keyboard (again <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>). Too much in order to enter a single character. I would rather prefer the ability to define my own key sequences.
Forgot to say that the reason to switch keyboards is that <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+U is entered like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Θ when Greek keyboard is on.

Comment: @user265585 http://askubuntu.com/questions/131044/how-can-i-input-punctuation-marks-like-ellipsis#comment396499_131077 below, and moreover: please note the linked question(s) to the right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is in the [**Unicode composition**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Unicode_composition) section of the [Ubuntu documentation for the ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Introduction). The next bit is based on the instructions in that section.

---

Another means to enter non-keycap characters is to enter them as a Unicode character number.

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

  Release <kbd>U</kbd> while continuing to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

  Enter the four hexadecimal digit (`0123456789abcdef`) number for the Unicode character code point. (An underlined <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the number will display as you type.)

  Release <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
- Another alternative is to press (and release) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. An underlined <kbd>u</kbd> is displayed.

  Enter the hexadecimal Unicode character code point

  Press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

---

I used the instructions above to create this string: `‘some text’ …` (Ta-Da!)

For whatever its worth, I found this by looking at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368/52923) to the question "[How can I type special characters like ë?](https://askubuntu.com/q/358/52923)".

This question was at the *top* of the list of links  **"Related"**  to your question. The **Related** links list is **always** present in the right hand sidebar of any question on a [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I don't believe you need to hold down Shift+Control. (I don't on my machine anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to type those characters using the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey):

- `‘` (U+2018): `compose key`, then `'`, `<`
- `’` (U+2019): `compose key`, then `'`, `>`
- `“` (U+201C): `compose key`, then `'`, `<`
- `”` (U+201D): `compose key`, then `"`, `>`
- `…` (U+2026): `compose key`, then `.`, `.`
- `—` (U+2014): `compose key`, then `-`, `-`, `-`
- `–` (U+2013): `compose key`, then `-`, `-`, `.`