# Problem With ë character in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: shortcut-keys

Hello Guys I have Ubuntu Desktop 13.04 and I can't type `ë`. And why I press

<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

Not displayed `ë` but another character.

This Character`é` 
is not the same with this character `ë`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Which ë are you exactly trying to type? There is such in the Cyrillic script used by the Russians, there is one in Albanian and a couple of other languages including Dutch, French etc. (think it's more of a dialect-thing there). Please provide information about your language and keyboard layout. Also make sure that the selected layout actually supports this kind of character. Call the layout chart by either typing "keyboard layout" in Unity Dash (go in the "Layouts" section; below the list of layouts you have there is a small keyboard-icon that calls the chart window of the currently selected layout in the list) or (much faster) right-clicking in the layout/language indicator in the indicator area (by default - top of the screen) and choosing "Show Layout Chart".

Comment: I want to use ë in Albanian.My keyboard Layout is English now for Now how to make ë in Albanian without change English Language in Keyboard.

Comment: If you don't want to change the layout, use the compose key combination. Check the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-e (same question as yours, I think)