# How to Get A with Dots in Dvorak of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dvorak, dead-keys

I want to type A with dots (`Ä` / `ä`) as one-level keybinding in Ubuntu 16.04's keyboard of Macbook Air 2013-mid, output of `setxkbmap -query`

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    dvorak,
options:    ctrl:nocaps
```

By default, there is no <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in the keyboard, just two Alts. This command makes your right alt the compose key (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>) but maintains your own custom keyboard configurations etc having Capslock as CTRL by `caps:ctrl_modifier`, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/784076/25388)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \
    "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \ 
    | sed "s/]/, 'compose:ralt']/")"
```

It would be really great to have `xmodmap` independent solution if this is going to be changed because it is going to be depreciated.

### Two-level keybinding approach

We can only do two-level keybinding approach with Dvorak International with deadkeys.

- SeverusTux's answer is two-level command as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, which works only in `us-drovak, international with deadkeys`.
- SeverusTux. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> +<kbd>e4</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> works and gives you `ä`. How can you map this to a one-level keybinding <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>?

I do where you see that the GUI make the change elsewhere. I really want to know where

```
masi@masi:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose > /home/masi/Desktop/test1
% I make here a change in the GUI as proposed by Severus: compose key = right Alt
masi@masi:~$ cat /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose > /home/masi/Desktop/test2
masi@masi:~$ diff /home/masi/Desktop/test1 /home/masi/Desktop/test2
[ no output ]
```

This shows that the xserver does not update fast. You have to change your keyboard to something else and back again, for the change.

### One-level Keybinding Approach

I want one-level command as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> for `ä` and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> for `Ä` in English(US-dvorak). 
I do `xev -e keyboard`  and press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>

```
[ignore the beginning; press AltGr]
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001, 
root 0xd6, subw 0x0, time 13661220, (186,522), root:(186,574), 
state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES, 
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False 

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001, 
root 0xd6, subw 0x0, time 13661284, (186,522), root:(186,574), 
state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES, 
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You can get all possible switches by `more /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst | grep lv3` but we are only interested in `lv3:ralt_switch`

```
  lv3:switch           Right Ctrl
  lv3:menu_switch      Menu
  lv3:win_switch       Any Win key
  lv3:lwin_switch      Left Win
  lv3:rwin_switch      Right Win
  lv3:alt_switch       Any Alt key
  lv3:lalt_switch      Left Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch      Right Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch_multikey Right Alt, Shift+Right Alt key is Compose
  lv3:ralt_alt         Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level
  lv3:enter_switch     Enter on keypad
  lv3:caps_switch      Caps Lock
  lv3:bksl_switch      Backslash
  lv3:lsgt_switch      &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  lv3:caps_switch_latch Caps Lock chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
  lv3:bksl_switch_latch Backslash chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
  lv3:lsgt_switch_latch &lt;Less/Greater&gt; chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
```

My keyboard layouts tested but main English(US-dvorak)

[image]

### Final solution [Sneetsher]

I set A with dots in English(dvorak) by <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>. Merge the changes in`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`; now German-Dvorak because it works very well for Scandinavian languages too (from [here](https://gist.github.com/sergeykish/650839#file-dvorak-de-diff))

```
// based on a keyboard map from an 'xkb/symbols/dk' file
// Added A with dots and O with dots for AltGr-A and AltGr-O, respectively. Sneether and Masi, 17-June-2016.

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "dvorak" {

    name[Group1]= "English (Dvorak)";

    key <TLDE> { [       grave, asciitilde, dead_grave, dead_tilde      ] };

    key <AE01> { [          1,  exclam          ]       };
    key <AE02> { [          2,  at              ]       };
    key <AE03> { [          3,  numbersign      ]       };
    key <AE04> { [          4,  dollar          ]       };
    key <AE05> { [          5,  percent         ]       };
    key <AE06> { [          6,  asciicircum, dead_circumflex, dead_circumflex ] };
    key <AE07> { [          7,  ampersand       ]       };
    key <AE08> { [          8,  asterisk        ]       };
    key <AE09> { [          9,  parenleft,  dead_grave] };
    key <AE10> { [          0,  parenright      ]       };
    key <AE11> { [ bracketleft, braceleft       ]       };
    key <AE12> { [ bracketright, braceright,  dead_tilde] };

    key <AD01> { [  apostrophe, quotedbl, dead_acute, dead_diaeresis    ] };
    key <AD02> { [      comma,  less,   dead_cedilla, dead_caron        ] };
    key <AD03> { [      period, greater, dead_abovedot, periodcentered  ] };
    key <AD04> { [          p,  P               ]       };
    key <AD05> { [          y,  Y               ]       };
    key <AD06> { [          f,  F               ]       };
    key <AD07> { [          g,  G               ]       };
    key <AD08> { [          c,  C               ]       };
    key <AD09> { [          r,  R               ]       };
    key <AD10> { [          l,  L               ]       };
    key <AD11> { [      slash,  question        ]       };
    key <AD12> { [      equal,  plus            ]       };

    key <AC01> {[ a,          A,    adiaeresis,       Adiaeresis ]      };
    key <AC02> {[ o,          O,    odiaeresis,       Odiaeresis ]      };
    key <AC03> { [ e, E, ediaeresis, Ediaeresis ] };
    key <AC04> { [ u, U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AC05> { [          i,  I               ]       };
    key <AC06> { [          d,  D               ]       };
    key <AC07> { [          h,  H               ]       };
    key <AC08> { [          t,  T               ]       };
    key <AC09> { [          n,  N               ]       };
    key <AC10> { [ s, S, ssharp ] };
    key <AC11> { [      minus,  underscore      ]       };

    key <AB01> { [   semicolon, colon, dead_ogonek, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AB02> { [          q,  Q               ]       };
    key <AB03> { [          j,  J               ]       };
    key <AB04> { [          k,  K               ]       };
    key <AB05> { [          x,  X               ]       };
    key <AB06> { [          b,  B               ]       };
    key <AB07> { [          m,  M               ]       };
    key <AB08> { [          w,  W               ]       };
    key <AB09> { [          v,  V               ]       };
    key <AB10> { [          z,  Z               ]       };

    key <BKSL> { [  backslash,  bar             ]       };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Or use the script which is however still buggy

```
# restore your current keyboard settings 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt', 'caps:ctrl_modifier']"

sudo sed -i.bak 's/[[ \t]*a,[ \t]*A[ \t]*]/[ a,          A,    adiaeresis,       Adiaeresis ]/g;' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us; 
sudo sed -i.bak 's/[[ \t]*o,[ \t]*O[ \t]*]/[ o,          O,    odiaeresis,       Odiaeresis ]/g;' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us; 
# German-Dvorak feels better
#sudo sed -i.bak 's/[[ \t]*e,[ \t]*E[ \t]*]/[ e,          E,    ediaeresis,       Ediaeresis ]/g;' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us; 
#sudo sed -i.bak 's/[[ \t]*u,[ \t]*U[ \t]*]/[ u,          U,    udiaeresis,       Udiaeresis ]/g;' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us; 
#sudo sed -i.bak 's/[[ \t]*s,[ \t]*S[ \t]*]/[ s,          S,    ssharp ]/g;' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us; 

# add     include "level3(ralt_switch)" to the end of the environment
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290407/16920
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290405/16920
pos=( $( sed -n -f - /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us <<END_SED
    /xkb_symbols "dvorak" {/,/^};/{
            /xkb_symbols "dvorak" {/=
            /^};/=
    }
END_SED
) )
sudo sed -i.bak "${pos[1]}i\    include \"level3(ralt_switch)\"" /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
# Change your keyboard. Change Back. Should work. But some bug. I cannot get the script works stably.
```

Bugs

1. TODO problem with reloading the keyboard back to xserver https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290449/16920 The manual change does not work always.
2. Complications: Xserver does not load those keys fast and not even in all cases after restart/logout.

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4 - 4.6
Keyboard model: pc105
Keyboard layout for two-level keybinding approach: US-dvorak international with deadkeys
Keyboard layout for one-level keybinding approach: *English (Dvorak)* = *US-dvorak*, but also *English (Classic Dvorak)*

Comment: Press **`ctrl+shift+u`** then type **`e4`** and press enter. If this works then you can try further to get a simple key for that.

Comment: I have written an answer for what I said earlier, please leave comments if you have any doubts

Answer (score 8):

- To type ä ,  unicode is U00E4
- To type Ä ,  unicode is U00C4

If you want the unicodes of other characters, you can get them from `gucharmap`

To enter it manually, press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>u</kbd>** and followed by 00e4 and hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** , this should type ä

But there is a better way to do this using **Compose Keys**.

**If you want to set your** <kbd>Right alt</kbd> **as the compose key using command line:** just execute this :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"
```

If you want to set it suing GUI :

Enable compose key by going to **System Settings --> Keyboard --> Typing --> Right Alt**. (you can chose a different key if you wish)

[image]

#### **Thats all !!**

Now go to your favorite text editor and do this :

Press and release **<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>** followed by **<kbd>"</kbd>** followed by **<kbd>a</kbd>**. now you should see **ä** .

The same can be done for **Ä** , Press and release **<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>** followed by **<kbd>"</kbd>** followed by **<kbd>A</kbd>**

**NOTE :** you might need to press **<kbd>Shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>'</kbd>** to get **<kbd>"</kbd>**

**TIP:**

If you wish to see all similar shortcuts view this file : **/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose**

Comment: @Masi That file is just a list of all Compose key combos. Just extra info.

Comment: @Masi you don't have to edit that file or replace anything with `sed`, that is extra info as @BharadwajRaju said, you can simply view it if you want the shortcut key for some other special symbol. That is a huge list of all such shortcuts

Comment: @Masi so you just want to set compose key using command line instead of using GUI ??

Comment: @Masi Answer updated :-) you don't need any script for doing that. just a simple command will do the trick. hope this is what you wanted

Comment: What did you use to make that awesome gif?  Nice touch.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti Thankyou **;-)** As it is not related to the question, Lets continue out discussion [***here***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti I have replied to you [***here***](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30302193#30302193)

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Mate?  I do not have this interface.  I need to type the pali character (a with a  line on top, l with a dot below, etc)  The ibus method crashes synapse.  Currently, I made a macro for LibreOffice, but I would like a global solution.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti Execute this command to know the shortcuts for your required letters : `cat /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | grep [ĀāḶḷ]` . You will get the shortcuts. And you don't need this interface. Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"` to set Right alt as your compose/multi key

Comment: I did that and then rebooted.  I typed right alt + a +minus    and it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41084/discussion-between-severus-tux-and-bhikkhu-subhuti). @BhikkhuSubhuti

Comment: I couldn't find this GUI settings menu in Ubuntu 20.04 to enable the Compose key, but I was able to do that in gnome-tweaks (a GUI as well).

Answer (score 7):

#### English (Dvorak, international with dead keys) - `dvorak-intl`  works fine!

I can type `Ä` using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> with default setup. See file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` where the `q` key declared as

```
key <AB02> { [ q, Q, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
```

and with `level3(ralt_switch)` at the bottom to use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>/<kbd>AltGr</kbd> as 3rd level shift such that

- 1st column `q` ← <kbd>q</kbd>
- 2nd column `Q` ← <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
- 3rd column `ä` ← <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
- 4th column `Ä` ← <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Visualization

[image: X11 XKB layout levels]

- `dvorak-intl` defines only 4 levels, I draw the all 8 levels as XKB supports so you can get general overview.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> is a standard level2 shift, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the default level3 shift for most layouts which need level3&4. Only few layouts define levels5,6,7,8 and so the level5 shift key, I used <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> just for explaination.
- All those 4 lines which define `<AB02>` key are equivalent.

---

#### Setting `ä` & `Ä` at 3rd &4th level of `a` key on English (Dvorak) - `dvorak` layout

Plus `ö` & `Ö` at`o` key. (It doesn't appear in screen-shot, as it was added after screen-shot)

Same as `dvorak-intl`, we can make same setup for `dvorak`.

1. Clear previous modifications

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
   ```
2. Checkpoint

   - Try English (Dvorak, international with dead keys) - `dvorak-intl`

     <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> prints `ä`.If it didn't work then it will be same problem with this setup. There is something prevent Right Alt from working as level3 shift.

     [image: English (Dvorak, international with dead keys)]
   - Verify the current map of `dvorak`

     [image: English (Dvorak)]
   - Verify Right Alt mapping, it should be `Alt_R`

     ```
     $ xev -e keyboard
     [ignore start things; press AltGr]

     KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
         root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 1855861, (769,284), root:(834,336),
         state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
         XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XFilterEvent returns: False

     KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
         root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 1855965, (769,284), root:(834,336),
         state 0x18, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
         XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XFilterEvent returns: False
     ```
3. Modify `a` map

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us +224

   key <AD11> { [      slash,  question        ]       };
   key <AD12> { [      equal,  plus            ]       };

   key <AC01> { [          a,  A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ]       };
   key <AC02> { [          o,  O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ]       };
   key <AC03> { [          e,  E               ]       };
   ```
4. Setting Right Alt as level3 shift

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us +248

       key <AB09> { [          v,  V               ]       };
       key <AB10> { [          z,  Z               ]       };

       key <BKSL> { [  backslash,  bar             ]       };

       include "level3(ralt_switch)"
   };

   // Dvorak international with dead keys
   ```

   There are many keys that can be used as ISO_Level3_Shift. Check available options

   ```
   $ more /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst | grep lv3:
     lv3:switch           Right Ctrl
     lv3:menu_switch      Menu
     lv3:win_switch       Any Win key
     lv3:lwin_switch      Left Win
     lv3:rwin_switch      Right Win
     lv3:alt_switch       Any Alt key
     lv3:lalt_switch      Left Alt
     lv3:ralt_switch      Right Alt
     lv3:ralt_switch_multikey Right Alt, Shift+Right Alt key is Compose
     lv3:ralt_alt         Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level
     lv3:enter_switch     Enter on keypad
     lv3:caps_switch      Caps Lock
     lv3:bksl_switch      Backslash
     lv3:lsgt_switch      &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
     lv3:caps_switch_latch Caps Lock chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
     lv3:bksl_switch_latch Backslash chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
     lv3:lsgt_switch_latch &lt;Less/Greater&gt; chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
   ```

   For example, if you like to use Caps Lock as the level3 shift then enter `include "level3(caps_switch)"` instead of `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`.
5. Force reload of layouts

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
   ```

   Change to another layout then back.
6. Check point

   - Verify the current map of `dvorak`

     [image: English (Dvorak)]
   - Verify Right Alt mapping. It should be `ISO_Level3_Shift`

     ```
     $ xev -e keyboard

     KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
         root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 4755266, (154,154), root:(219,206),
         state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
         XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
         XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XFilterEvent returns: False

     KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
         root 0x281, subw 0x0, time 4755435, (154,154), root:(219,206),
         state 0x80, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
         XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
         XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
         XFilterEvent returns: False
     ```

Now, it should work!

---

#### One-liner command

```
cd /; \
echo -e "--- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us\t2016-01-22 09:38:25.000000000 +0100\n+++ /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us\t2016-06-17 15:43:07.656076074 +0100\n@@ -221,8 +221,8 @@\n     key <AD11> { [\tslash,\tquestion\t]\t};\n     key <AD12> { [\tequal,\tplus\t\t]\t};\n \n-    key <AC01> { [\t    a,\tA \t\t]\t};\n-    key <AC02> { [\t    o,\tO\t\t]\t};\n+    key <AC01> { [\t    a,\tA, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ]\t};\n+    key <AC02> { [\t    o,\tO, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ]\t};\n     key <AC03> { [\t    e,\tE\t\t]\t};\n     key <AC04> { [\t    u,\tU\t\t]\t};\n     key <AC05> { [\t    i,\tI\t\t]\t};\n@@ -245,6 +245,8 @@\n     key <AB10> { [\t    z,\tZ\t\t]\t};\n \n     key <BKSL> { [  backslash,  bar             ]       };\n+\n+    include \"level3(ralt_switch)\"\n };\n \n // Dvorak international with dead keys\n" \
| sudo patch -p1; \
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data; \
cl=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current); \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0; \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1; \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current "$cl"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41197/discussion-on-answer-by-sneetsher-how-to-get-a-with-dots-in-dvorak-of-ubuntu-16).

Comment: I have found out that the manual change of the keyboard does not work always. The change is not valid until you log out. I am thinking a solution here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290449/how-to-reload-xserver-after-a-change-in-keyboard-layout

Comment: I found a bug which I do not understand. This line `sudo sed -i "${pos[1]}i\    include 'level3(ralt_switch)'" /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` makes the keyboard unusable at the startup. You cannot type any key in the keyboard. It just adds level3 at the end Dvorak environment at the line 249. Is the line 249 correct position?

Comment: @Masi, yep but it should be in 248 not 249! and sure you have `${pos[1]}`  defined  before.

Comment: I opened a new thread about the case here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346073/16920 because I really need such features more stably in the OS.