# How to have programmer-friendly Dvorak with deadkeys in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, xmodmap, dvorak, dead-keys

The current keyboard layout Dvorak with deadkeys is horrible. 
All those "¨` are under one key which is not practical for a programmer. 
OSX has well distributed programmer keys in Dvorak with deadkeys.

Please, feel free to propose solutions that work independently of `xmodmap` because it is going be deprecated.

How can you change the keybinding of the active-deadkey button in Ubuntu?
How can you make better Dvorak with deadkeys for a programmer in Ubuntu?

Comment: Shameless plug: http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/  --- but you can also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter (although `xmodmap` is depecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use deadkeys for programmer friendly typing. Use English(Dvorak) with first-level customization with AltGr (Compose Key) for German/Finnish/Swedish/... as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/648659/25388). Switch to Plover steno when your ankles hurt too much. 
Xmodmap will be deprecated (according to some source) so better to independent solutions about it later.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the way how Ubuntu 16.04 has solved the case on Macbook Air, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Saucy#Backtick_and_tilde_keys) but I like the reverse way better about the fix in Macbook and PC. The tilde and backtick key will print the greater than and less than symbol, which I really like. 
This is very convenient also in PCs,  and original [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1486995).
Edit `~/.xmodmaprc`

```
keycode 60 = grave asciitilde
```

Run

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
```

Find your keys by `xmodmap -pk | grep greater`; I really like the following configuration

```
    60         0x002e (period) 0x003e (greater)        
    93         0x003c (less)   0x003e (greater)        0x007c (bar)    0x00a6 
(brokenbar)      0x007c (bar)    0x00a6 (brokenbar)
```

Comment: I moved the thread about proposals without `xmodmap` here http://askubuntu.com/q/648659/25388 for clarity.

Comment: Ok, the other thread is not clearly about deadkeys, but there may come solutions that are useful also here. But feel free to propose here also solutions that work independently of `xmodmap`.