# Remapping arrow keys to alt+j/k/l/i

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've just spent a good while trying to make this happen, but I'm just stuck on the basic hello world example.

I've navigated to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and edited the us file (since I use a standard us keyboard) and changed the first instance of

`key <AC08> {   [     k,    K       ]   };`

into

`key <AC08> {   [     k,    K, A        ]   };`

I also deleted the .xkm files in /var/lib/xkb and rebooted. According to

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions

I should now expect to see a capital A upon rightalt+k, but I get nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: I have the same problem and no progress. It is fascinating how difficult such a simple thing is.

Comment: @user3496846 quiet late, but I posted a solution that should work and tested it some time before.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You need to set/activate 3rd level shift (Default is: AltGr / Right Alt)

So use [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/783984/26246) as reference which also explains it.

1. Declare either 2, 4, 8, i don't know if it will work otherwise

   ```
   key <AC08> {   [     k,    K,    a,    A]   };
   ```
2. Add this line at the end, to activate <kbd>RAlt</kbd> as 3rd level shift

   ```
   level3(ralt_switch)
   ```
3. Reload XKB data

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
   ```

I recommend creating new inherited instead of modification which will be overwritten on updates. Check [How to add a new keyboard layout (Custom keyboard layout definition)](https://askubuntu.com/q/482678/26246) or [What are the steps needed to create new keyboard layout on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/510024/26246)