# How to Make Capslock Control without xmodmap/XKBOPTIONS?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 16.04, shortcut-keys, dvorak

`xmodmap` is depreciated and does not work with `gsettings`, doing this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/784005/25388) disables my `xmodmap` etc `sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard` > `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` and `sudo setxkbmap dvorak '' ctrl:nocaps`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"
```

I would like to do the change of capslock to Ctrl by `gsettings`. However, I do not find such a possibility in the settings. I think this change can be reached by `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Custom Shortcuts` > `+` but I am not sure how it could be done with gnome.

---

How can you change capslock to Ctrl by gnome-settings?

Comment: Did you try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt','ctrl:nocaps']"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `'caps:ctrl_modifier'` to the value of `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` in gsettings, for example

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt', 'caps:ctrl_modifier']"
```

You can use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options | sed "s/]/, 'caps:ctrl_modifier']/")"
```

to append on to the current value of `xkb-options`. You can find more possible option in the "OPTIONS" section of the [xkeyboard-config manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html)

To change your keyboard layout you need to set the value of `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`, e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+dvorak')]"
```

if you want to only use Dvorak or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+dvorak'), ('xkb', 'us')]"
```

if you want to be able to switch between Dvorak and standard layout.

See the "LAYOUTS" section of the [xkeyboard-config manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html) for more layouts. You need to substitute the parents so that e.g. `us(dvorak)` becomes `us+dvorak`.

The XKB settings from gsettings are loaded by GNOME at startup and overwrite any previous settings. To use `setxkbmap` you need to make sure that your `setxkbmap` are run after the GNOME settings are applied. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Great! Very good! It works! Can you please tell your source for `caps:ctrl_modifiel`? I want to know where to look later for improvements. Do you understand why `gsettings` replaces the command of `setxkbmap`? How can you add here too that make Dvorak your keyboard layout? I think it is just `sudo setxkbmap dvorak ''`, since your command does not replace it.

Comment: Running `man xkeyboard-config` gives you a huge list of mapping possibilities. It is also available online [here](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config#Options-Caps_Lock_key_behavior)

Comment: @Masi  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Assume you the user has empty configs like `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"`. Running your second command will fail and give output `@as [, 'compose:ralt']
       ^`. I do not want to run the first command because it replaces all user things. How can you fix the situation here?

Answer (score 0):

@florian-diesch's answer is great, but I thought it would be worth adding a version that will also work in the case that the user has an empty config:

```
# Map Caps Lock to Ctrl.
XKB_OPTIONS="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options)"
[ "$(echo ${XKB_OPTIONS} | grep -v '\[\]')" ] && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "$(echo ${XKB_OPTIONS} | sed "s/\[\]/['caps:ctrl_modifier']/")"
[ "$(echo ${XKB_OPTIONS} | grep -v 'caps:ctrl_modifier')" ] && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "$(echo ${XKB_OPTIONS} | sed "s/\]/, 'caps:ctrl_modifier']/")"
```