# how to enable compose key in cinnamon?

Tags: 16.10, cinnamon, compose-key

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with Cinnamon, and I'd really like to be able to  type diacritics.  I saw this post:

[How can I type accentuated characters like ë?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-%C3%AB)

But I can't seem to set a "compose" key.  I go into Settings->Keyboard->Layout->Options.

I expand "Position of Compose Key", and choose "Right Alt".

But...nothing happens.   If I go into LibreOffice and type:

RightAlt:  nothing happens
Shift-Quote:  I get a double-quote
e: I get a lowercase letter "e"

But what I want is the "e" with the umlaut (?) above it.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about Cinnamon, but a generic way to designate <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as a compose key is to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and change the line:

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to:

```
XKBOPTIONS="compose:ralt"
```

Another way to do what you want is to use a keyboard layout with dead keys. With e.g. *English (US, international with dead keys)* you can type ë by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>E</kbd>. (I'm guessing that you have a US physical keyboard.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to /etc/default/keyboard.  I can't get the right "alt" key to work, but I can set "compose:menu", and that works.

Comment: Well, it worked for a minute, and then stopped :(

Comment: @ChrisCurvey: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I'm using "English (US)"

Comment: @ChrisCurvey: That's what I guessed. And it's strange that "compose:ralt" doesn't work. Anyway, I also pointed you to another method to type letters with diacritics, which you may want to explore.

Comment: @drumfire: Irrelevant. This resource is about Ubuntu.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson derp, sorry, I wasn't paying attention. Deleted my remark.

Answer (score 6):

Run the keyboard application (from menu or from the settings).

Choose the Layouts tab.

At the right bottom of the window, you've a Options... button.

You've then access to different options, including "Keyboard Layout Options".

Comment: In "Keyboard Layout Options", you have "Position of Compose Key"

Answer (score 3):

1. **Menu**
2. **Preferences** » **System Settings**
3. **Keyboard** (under Hardware)
4. **Layouts** tab
5. **Options...** (bottom right)
6. Expand **Position of Compose Key**
7. Check **Right Alt** (or other key if you prefer)

[image: Position of Compose Key Screenshot]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. Thank you.