# Reference for special character input with dead keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

On Linux/Ubuntu, I have found a few options for entering special characters:

- **`AltGr+Key`** and `Shift+AltGr+Key` on keyboards that have `AltGr`; those can be found on the Keyboard Layout Chart in Ubuntu. For example, `Shift+AltGr+Q` produces Ω.
  [image: Keyboard layout chart on Ubuntu]
- **Unicode input** with `Shift+Ctrl+U <unicode> <RET>`, which works in almost all applications in Ubuntu 17.04 and in GTK applications for older Ubuntu versions and other distributions. For example, `Shift+Ctrl+U 2209 <RET>` creates ∉
- The **[Compose key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-%c3%ab)** which, after enabling, combines two characters to one, for example `<Compose> 1 2` produces ½ or `<Compose> B .` produces Ḃ.
- And finally, **dead keys** like ~ and ^ which do not immediately produce a character but modify the keyboard layout for the next key press. For example, `~ a` produces ã, `~ =` produces ≃, `^ i` produces î, and `^ ^` produces ^.

Where can I find a reference for dead keys?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you understand this quite well. What kind of reference is it you would like to see?

Comment: Something like [this list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkDeadKeyTable) which lists all possible characters that can be produced with dead keys.

Comment: To use dead keys, they need to be available in the keyboard layout you are using. For instance, to see which dead keys are present in the _German (Switzerland)_ layout, you can study the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ch`file. Considering that, the usefulness of such a complete reference appears to be limited. Doesn't the Gtk list you pointed at provide sufficient guidance?

Comment: It does almost (I found it after posting this question).  It would help a bit more to really see the character that is produced instead of a textual description. But if there is no such list, then so be it. Thanks for the hint about xkb symbols, that looks like a good source of truth once one understands how it works.

Comment: Background: I want to find out if I can create letters like the ộ in the city name [Hội An](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%E1%BB%99i_An) without the unicode input method. With an overview table this is easy to confirm or deny.

Comment: I see. I don't think there exist dead keys for characters as special as the one you mentioned. If you often need to type those, you may want to consider a custom keyboard layout.