# How can I type special characters instead of a keystroke on Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, macosx, remapping

I know there are solutions such as using the keypad to encode ASCII code or using special keys to map accent.

But I am looking for a solution like in http://osxdaily.com/2017/03/22/type-accents-mac-easy/

I understand the complexity of having both a keyboard mapping and a UI that shows the selections you can do since Linux core and desktop environments are separated, plus it might not work in non-graphical environments.

But is there a way to configure this mapping (or does it exist already) in a way that we could press for example <kbd>e</kbd>, holding it while pressing <kbd>1</kbd> and have an <kbd>è</kbd>. does this can conflict with things like the terminal or os keybinding?

if it does not exist, where could I find the resources to develop it?
for once, I agree with an OSX principle: keystroke is not very useful and could result in alternate inputs instead.

EDIT: I am looking if the OSX mapping already exists before doing my own, and if it doesn't and I want to do it, is there a way to do it without a compose key?

Comment: check out http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html

Comment: and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-%C3%AB?rq=1