# Is there a way to type accented characters in a similar fashion than the one in macOS?

Tags: keyboard-layout, mac

On a Mac I can easily write in French using my American keyboard, see the second topic here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586
Is there a way to have this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I think you have to go to 'text entry' in settings and add Canadian multilingual.  Might have to switch back and forth, for keyboards with extra symbols on keys.  Can also check this question.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accented-characters-like-ë?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add the *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* keyboard layout and switch to it to type accented characters easy.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: I added it, it is not as easy as the mac way though:
!"Type accented characters
Press and hold a key until its alternate characters appear, then click or type the number under the character that you want to use.



If no additional characters are available for the key that you're holding, the accent menu doesn't appear."!

Comment: @ziulfer: Ah, is that the mac way? Something like that is applied in the [screen keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html). But AFAIK it can not be achieved for an ordinary keyboard via an XKB layout.