# How to type all Dutch letters (e.g. "ó") on using ibus + standard English keyboard?

Tags: ibus, localization

How can one be able to type all contemporary letters in Dutch language on ubuntu or debian using *ibus* and a standard English *qwerty* keyboard? E.g., the letter "ó" in the word "vóór" (means "before"). Solutions meeting the following conditions are strongly preferred:

- A Dutch input module (not German or something else).
- Installable via a `.deb` package or Ubuntu package manager.
- No mouse action is required to input these letters.

I am using a standard English *qwerty* keyboard with *ibus* input framework. `Ibus Preferences -> Input Method -> Add` has only a `Dutch; Flemish - Belgian` module available for Dutch that appears to be unable to achieve what I am asking for (although ö, ô and è can be typed).

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accented-characters-like-%C3%AB

Comment: Oh yeah, I somehow overlooked the compose key. I thought it was mac-specific but in fact the right `Alt` key does the same thing. With this knowledge in mind, `ò` can be input via `Compose + \, o` using the built-in Dutch input...Thanks for the prompt help!

Comment: Yes, it does. I cannot close this as duplicate. Should I just delete this post?

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate, the system will take care of it eventually.